# Returning an array of all the pet names

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

If I were to create a function, were a persons name was entered, how would I return an array with the names of the pets from the object below, what would be the best method if I were to use a for loop to iterate over it? I've not quite learnt some of the ES6 features yet and i'm new to coding.

A typical array of owners is shown below:

[
{
name: 'Malcolm',
pets: ['Bear', 'Minu'],
},
{
name: 'Caroline',
pets: ['Basil', 'Hamish'],
},
];

Thanks for the fast replies! :)

Comment: Do you mean something like this? for (let i = 0; i < people.length; i++) { return people[i].pets }

Comment: i thnk i misread your question. it is a find problem. ignore my last comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty simple to achieve it:
you search for the corresponding owner with the find function, then, if you have an owner, you return the pets key, which is already an array according to the code provided. If you have no owner corresponding to the name entered, then you'll get "undefined", but you can customise this code to have an empty array if it better fits your needs.

```js
const data = [{
  name: 'Malcolm',
  pets: ['Bear', 'Minu'],
}, {
  name: 'Caroline',
  pets: ['Basil', 'Hamish'],
}, ];

const getPetsByOwnerName = (ownerName) => {
  const owner = data.find(d => d.name === ownerName);
  return owner ? owner.pets : undefined;
}

const carolinePets = getPetsByOwnerName('Caroline');

console.log(carolinePets);
```

EDIT: author request to do it with a loop

```js
const data = [{
  name: 'Malcolm',
  pets: ['Bear', 'Minu'],
}, {
  name: 'Caroline',
  pets: ['Basil', 'Hamish'],
}, ];

function getPetsByOwnerNameWithLoop(ownerName) {
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i].name === ownerName) {
        return data[i].pets;
    }
  }
  
  return undefined;
}

const carolinePets = getPetsByOwnerNameWithLoop('Caroline');

console.log(carolinePets);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sorry to be a pain, I'm not quite familiar with arrow functions, is there anyway you could show me how to do it by writing out a simple for loop? Thanks

Comment: @npgs I've updated my answer with a loop version. However, I advise you to really learn what ES6 brought to JavaScript as you'll see a lot of code using theses new features. It will help you write less code too, simpler functions.

Comment: You're a star. Thank you so much. I had a similar idea of code but I forgot to put the if statement in. Again, thanks for the help, it's much appreciated!

Comment: Hi yeah of course, I can't upvote at the moment because my account is new but I will mark it as correct if I'm able to. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try filter() method. The function returns an array of names from the filtered owner as a result.

**Example code:**

```js
const arr = [
    { name: 'Malcolm', pets: ['Bear', 'Minu'], },
    { name: 'Caroline', pets: ['Basil', 'Hamish'], }
];

function petsNames(val) {
    return arr.filter(x => x.name === val)[0].pets;    
};

console.log(petsNames('Malcolm'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let ownersArray = [ { name: 'Malcolm', pets: ['Bear', 'Minu'], }, { name: 'Caroline', pets: ['Basil', 'Hamish'], }, ];

const petArray = (owner, ownersArray) => {
let array = ownersArray.filter((arr) => arr.name===owner)

  return array.length>0  ? array[0].pets : 'owner not found'

}
console.log(petArray("Caroline", ownersArray))
```